# Replacing QListView items that are dropped onto

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a QTreeView and a QListView. Both of these use the QStandardItemModel as models. The QTreeView should not accept drops. The QListView should accept drops.

If an item is dragged from the QTreeView and dropped onto an item in the QListView, then a copy of the item dragged from the QTreeView should replace the item in the QListView that it is dropped onto. If an item is dragged from the QTreeView and dropped at the top of the QListView, or between existing items in the QListView, or at the bottom of the QListView, then it should be copied to there.

If an item is dragged from the QListView and dropped onto an item in the QListView, then it should be moved to replace the item in the QListView that it is dropped onto. If an item is dragged from the QListView and dropped at the top of the QListView, or between existing items in the QListView, or at the bottom of the QListView, then it should be moved to there.

The items in the QTreeView should not be editable. Once they are copied to the QListView they should become editable in the QListView.

Answer (score 0):

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

import sys


def decode_byte_array(byte_array):
    role_value_dict_list = []

    data_stream = QDataStream(byte_array, QIODevice.ReadOnly)
    while not data_stream.atEnd():
        row = data_stream.readInt32()
        column = data_stream.readInt32()
        count = data_stream.readInt32()

        role_value_dict = {}
        for i in range(count):
            role = data_stream.readInt32()
            value = QVariant()
            data_stream >> value
            role_value_dict[Qt.ItemDataRole(role)] = value

        role_value_dict_list.append(role_value_dict)

    return role_value_dict_list


class MyListModel(QStandardItemModel):
    def dropMimeData(self, data, action, row, column, parent):
        if data.hasFormat('application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist'):
            byte_array = QByteArray(data.data("application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist"))
            role_value_dict_list = decode_byte_array(byte_array)
            item_list = []
            for role_value_dict in role_value_dict_list:
                item = QStandardItem()
                for role, value in role_value_dict.items():
                    item.setData(value, role)

                item.setEditable(True)
                item_list.append(item)


            parent_item = self.itemFromIndex(parent)

            if row == -1 and column == -1:
                if parent_item == None:
                    # Drop is after last row.
                    for item in item_list:
                        self.appendRow(item)

                else:
                    # Drop is on row.
                    self.setItem(parent.row(), parent.column(), item_list[0])
                    row = parent.row() + 1

                    for item in item_list[1:]:
                        self.insertRow(row, item)
                        row = row + 1

            elif row >= 0 and column >= 0:
                # Drop is before first row or between rows.
                for item in item_list:
                    self.insertRow(row, item)
                    row = row + 1

            else:
                return False

        else:
            return False

        return True


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        layout = QHBoxLayout()


        tree_view_model = QStandardItemModel()

        parent_item = tree_view_model.invisibleRootItem()

        item_1 = QStandardItem('item 1')
        item_1.setDragEnabled(False)
        item_1.setEditable(False)

        item_2 = QStandardItem('item 2')
        item_2.setEditable(False)

        item_3 = QStandardItem('item 3')
        item_3.setEditable(False)

        item_1.appendRow(item_2)
        item_1.appendRow(item_3)
        parent_item.appendRow(item_1)

        tree_view = QTreeView()
        tree_view.setModel(tree_view_model)

        tree_view.setHeaderHidden(True)
        tree_view.header().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        tree_view.setDragEnabled(True)


        list_view_model = MyListModel()

        list_view = QListView()
        list_view.setModel(list_view_model)

        list_view.setDragEnabled(True)
        list_view.setAcceptDrops(True)
        list_view.setDefaultDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)
        list_view.setDragDropOverwriteMode(False)
        list_view.setSelectionBehavior(QListView.SelectRows)
        list_view.setSelectionMode(QListView.SingleSelection)


        layout.addWidget(tree_view)
        layout.addWidget(list_view)


        centralWidget.setLayout(layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)


app = QApplication([])

f = QFont('Courier')
f.setPointSize(16)

app.setFont(f)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```